# How to visually display 3 phase output

Tags: led, ac, three-phase, vfd

We have inherited a PCB and must redesign it. Unfortunately, only the PCB was provided, no schematics or documentation.

I know the PCB controls a VFD (which we have been given) and whilst I know we can measure its output on an oscilloscope (which we will do), we have been asked to build a demo of the system working (using LEDs and switches to mimic the usual inputs and outputs to the PCB).

The three phase VFD will output different frequencies and it would be good if we could visualise this during the demo instead of using the oscilloscope. I thought about using LEDs (one per phase) and stepping the voltage down from the mains out to a lower voltage. However this would result in the LEDs flashing/ flickering at different speeds (I believe the VFD output is from 30Hz to 60Hz) so doing this might give everyone a sore head by looking at it for too long.

Any ideas of something I could use to visually demonstrate the VFD output without using an oscilloscope? (If it can be panel mounted, that's a bonus).

Comment: Make/download an animation beforehand, then show it..

Comment: This may be trickier than it sounds; if you connect 3 scope channels to UVW, you won't see what you think you'll see.  Keep in mind the ground clips are all connected electrically.  To see the *real waveforms* would require three *isolated* scopes.  Even then, the signals are PWM, not sinusoidal, so you'd get flickering at the PWM frequency (likely 1, 2, 4, 8kHz.)

Comment: Might be able to "fake it" if one scope can also do three math channels: U-V, V-W, W-U.

Comment: Connect it to a motor!

Answer (score 0):

The cheap $50 oscilloscopes/graphical multimeters will work for this great. E.g. [KKmoon KKM828](https://www.ebay.com/itm/403609285318). Since this is a work project, your time isn't free, so you can't beat 3 x $50 for a graphical scope display. You can mount those on a panel, and reuse them for other things when the project is over.